# How to have sub-numbering in an algorithm

Tags: algorithm2e

Below is a Dummy Algorithm code. I am not getting the desired output with this code. The code is as follows:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
>
> \usepackage[ruled, lined, linesnumbered, commentsnumbered,
> longend]{algorithm2e} \usepackage{xcolor}
>
> \begin{document}
>
> \newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\small\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
> \SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
>
> \begin{algorithm}
> \SetKwFunction{isOddNumber}{isOddNumber}
> % \SetKwInput{Input}{Input}
> % \SetKwInput{Output}{Output}
> \SetKwInOut{KwIn}{Input}
> \SetKwInOut{KwOut}{Output}
>
> \KwIn{A list where each element is an integer.}
>
> \KwOut{Processed list.}
>
> First List is follows
> \begin{itemize}
> \item One
> \item Two
> \item Three
> \end{itemize}
> Second List is follows
> \begin{itemize}
> \item Four
> \item Five
> \item Six
> \end{itemize}
> \caption{A plain algorithm} \end{algorithm} \end{document}
> ```

I want output as:

```
  1. First List is as follows

     i.   One
     ii.  Two
     iii. Three

  2. Second List is as follows
     i.   Four
     ii.  Five
     iii. Six
```

The above latex code can't retain its numbering sequence i.e., 2. is not printed in the output. Also, bullet points are in dot form and I want alphabetic and there is a space between each sub-numbering that I don't as my actual algorithm is quite long.

Comment: Your MWE is not minimal. Remove the unnecessary packages. MWE should actually be **minimal**.

Comment: You're not really utilising [`algorithm2e`](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) notation/functionality. How about [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86bj9.png) instead ([code](https://pastebin.com/raw/TbZwUBGC))?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Werner. The code is working as desired. The only thing left is the indent of sub-numbers.

Comment: @TriptiAgrawal: Line numbers in an algorithm is meant to be flush left, regardless of the indentation of the code. At least, you'll find that in all algorithm packages.

Comment: In the algorithm, I have everything inside for loop. It is a big algorithm and it is a part of unpublished research work, so I can't post the actual algorithm. In my algorithm, due to for loop, sub-numbering is appearing very far and it is looking odd.

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you want something like this -

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\let\@alph\@roman
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First List as follows
\begin{enumerate}
    \item One
    \item Two
    \item Three
\end{enumerate}
\item Second List is follows
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Four
    \item Five
    \item Six
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is one problem that your code is not changing the sequence number of line "Second List is as follows"

Comment: Tripti see the edit.